# Docusign - SignTab and Sign Anywhere in document

Tags: docusignapi

I would like send an envelope with below two options.

Here we go,

1. User should sign in SignTab if it is first page of document.
2. User can sign anywhere if it is other that first page.

Is it possible to have this option using docusign API.

If Yes, Please let me know what are the parameters should I send?

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure if this is possible.  On a given DocuSign envelope, if you do not set any tabs for a recipient then it becomes a free-form signing experience, which means they can place tabs anywhere on any page.  But if you set 1 or more tabs then they can only take actions where you've laid out the tabs. I'm not sure if you can mix these on a per page basis (I don't believe you can) but hopefully someone else can chime in if possible...

Comment: @Ergin is correct, that setting is an Envelope setting, not per page/document

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can only have it one way or the other currently- either you make the signing experience a Free Form signing experience (meaning the recipients can place tabs anywhere they want on any page of the envelope), OR you set 1 or more tabs in the envelope document(s) and the recipient will only be able to take action on those tabs and they will not be able to place tabs wherever they want.

The DocuSign Developer Center has a page devoted to Stick-eTabs under the `Features` section, they also talk about Free Form signing further down:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs